# psycopg2 - Unkeyed Connection error in multithreading

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am implementing connection pooling with Postgres for a multithreading application, Here I am creating two pools and storing in a singleton instance to be able to access the same instance from the entire application with the class RepositoryConnPool
Then we have the second class that is for context management, this I made to be able to execute multiple query's with the same connection in a `with` context, I have two pools of connections because when I execute a query i want to be able to execute a select query to replica database and modification of data to the master database. I am getting the following error while executing in a multithreading environment. This is not happening while I run without multithreading. Here is the error log :

ERROR   ;2020-06-03 11:05:42,826; ThreadPoolExecutor-0_4; modules.table_modify_module; table_modify_module:insert_host;60: trying to put unkeyed connection

ERROR   ;2020-06-03 11:05:42,826; ThreadPoolExecutor-0_21; table_modify_module; table_modify_module:insert_host;60: trying to put unkeyed connection

ERROR   ;2020-06-03 11:05:42,885; ThreadPoolExecutor-0_12; table_modify_module; table_modify_module:get_inst_detail;367: trying to put unkeyed connection

```
class RepositoryConnPool:

    __instance = None

    #This method overcharge is to make use of singleton pattern
    def __new__(cls):
        if cls.__instance is None:
            cls.__instance = object.__new__(cls)
        return cls.__instance

    def __init__(self):
        try:

            #I get connection details from vault
            inventory_master = vm.get_secret_by_base_path("xxxxxx")
            inventory_repl = vm.get_secret_by_base_path("xxxxx")


            self.repo_connection_pool_master = self.setup_conn_pool(inventory_master)

            self.repo_connection_pool_repl = self.setup_conn_pool(inventory_repl)

        except Exception as e:
            logger.error("GET repository address failed: ", exc_info=e)

    def setup_conn_pool(self,inventory_data):
        repo_dbausername = 'dba_admin'
        repo_dbapassword = inventory_data['accounts']['dba_admin']['password']
        repo_host = inventory_data['fqdn']
        repo_port = inventory_data['port']

        try:
            repo_connection_pool = psycopg2.pool.ThreadedConnectionPool(10, 30, user=repo_dbausername,
                                                                          password=repo_dbapassword,
                                                                          host=repo_host,
                                                                          port=repo_port,
                                                                          database="xxxxx")
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(e)

        return  repo_connection_pool


    #This method will fetch a connection from pool
    def get_master_connection(self):
        return self.repo_connection_pool_master.getconn()

    def get_repl_connection(self):
        return self.repo_connection_pool_repl.getconn()




class RepositoryConnection:

    #Gets connection from RepositoryConnPool
    def __init__(self):
        self.repo_conn_pool = RepositoryConnPool()
        self._repo_conn_master = self.repo_conn_pool.get_master_connection()
        self._repo_conn_repl = self.repo_conn_pool.get_repl_connection()

    def execute_query(self, query, commit=False, call_master = False, retry_count = 0):
        cursor = None
        try:
            if query.strip().upper().startswith("SELECT") and call_master == False:
                repo_query = query
                cursor = self._repo_conn_repl.cursor()
                cursor.execute(repo_query)
                if commit:
                    self._repo_conn_repl.commit()
                else:
                    try:
                        result = cursor.fetchall()
                        return result
                    except:
                        logging.info(f"Query executed:{query} and no result was returned")

            else:
                repo_query = query
                cursor = self._repo_conn_master.cursor()
                cursor.execute(repo_query)
                if commit:
                    self._repo_conn_master.commit()
                else:
                    try:
                        result = cursor.fetchall()
                        return result
                    except:
                        logging.info(f"Query executed:{query} and no result was returned")
        #This needs to change to handle connection error connection in different way
        except Exception as e:

            if(retry_count < 3):
                logger.warning(f"There was an error during execution of query, retry will be done {query} ")
                return self.execute_query(query,commit,call_master = True, retry_count= retry_count+1 )
            else:
                logger.fatal("All 3 connection retry failed")



        finally:
            if cursor:
                cursor.close()

    #Checks if connection is up
    def __enter__(self):
        try:
            if self._repo_conn_master and self._repo_conn_repl:
                return self
            else:
                raise Exception()
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(e)



    #Returns connection to pool
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        if self._repo_conn_master:
            self.repo_conn_pool.repo_connection_pool_master.putconn(self._repo_conn_master)
        if self._repo_conn_repl:
            self.repo_conn_pool.repo_connection_pool_repl.putconn(self._repo_conn_repl)
```

Comment: Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48877824/psycopg2-unkeyed-connection

Comment: Not the same issue, there he is not returning the connection.

Comment: ... you are returning something that seems to `_putconn` being no connection.

Comment: Sorry i did not get what you mean  by that

Comment: Have a look at [pscopg2's source code](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/blob/779a1370ceeac130de07edc0510f2c55846be1bd/lib/pool.py#L103), the error `trying to put unkeyed connection` is raised when a connection is put back that is not found.

Comment: How do you use `RepositoryConnection` ?, does the error always appear ?

Comment: At first i used it in a single thread environment and it worked, it started giving this error when I started using multiple workers